# How to remove input checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

I have a plugin which generates dynamically a list of categories.
I want to remove the input type checkbox select only from "Country" with jQuery.  I have already tried with remove selector (on class `.cat-item-15`) but couldn't manage to make it work. Only for the specific `li` which is "Country". This way it removes all.

Is it possible to be applied only on "Country" `li` ?

I tried this way :

```
$(".cat-item-15 :checkbox").remove();
```

And here is the code I need to alter :

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-15">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="15"> Country</label>
  <ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-53">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="53"> Canada</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-47">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="47"> United Kingdom</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-52">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="52"> USA</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
$(".cat-item-15 :checkbox").first().remove();
```

or

```
$(".cat-item-15 :checkbox[value='15']").remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/azxhnbxm/)**

When you tried `$(".cat-item-15 :checkbox").remove();` it failed because it selects all checkboxes that are descendants of any element with the class of `cat-item-15`, which was obviously too many.

`:checkbox[value='15']` only selects checkboxes that have a value attribute of 15, and `.first()` just selects the first checkbox, so given your code either should work.

Comment: Thank you ! Now it is working fine when i add the first selector.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider targeting the element in a few ways.

**Target The Element Based On Its Value**

jQuery supports [attribute-based selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) which will allow you to target a specific element based on the value of one of it's attributes, so in this case, you could use :

```
$('.cat-item-15 :checkbox[value="15"]').remove();
```

**Target The Element Based On Its Position**

Since you know this will be the first checkbox that appears, you could remove it by using the [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector :

```
$('.cat-item-15 :checkbox:first').remove();
```

**Target The Element Based On Nearby Contents**

Since you want to target the element that contains "Country", you can use the [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to find the particular `<label>` that contains that and remove it entirely :

```
$('.cat-item-15 label:contains("Country")').remove();
```

Comment: That's very good suggestion to use the nearby content definitely going to save this solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach didn't work because the way that HTML is structured, all the other items are nested within the initial `<li>`. So if you remove that parent `<li>`, all the items within it will be removed as well.

If you want to remove just the input checkbox you can do something like:

`$(".cat-item-15 :checkbox").first().remove();`

If you need the word "Country" to disappear as well, then:

`$(".cat-item-15 label").first().remove();`

should work I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.cat-item-15 :checkbox').css("display") == "none";
```

or

```
$('.cat-item-15 :checkbox').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below code:

```
$(".cat-item-15 input[type='checkbox']").remove();
```

It is so because,  the input is a child of `cat-item-15`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('.cat-item label:contains(Country) input').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-15"><label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="15"> Country</label>
  <ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-53"><label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="53"> Canada</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-47"><label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="47"> United Kingdom</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-52"><label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="52"> USA</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to remove checkbox in Country

```
$(".cat-item-15").children("label").children("input").remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use immediate child selector, if the structure needs to be same and value may be variable:

```js
$(".cat-item-15 > label input:checkbox").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-15">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="15"> Country</label>
  <ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-53">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="53"> Canada</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-47">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="47"> United Kingdom</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-52">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="52"> USA</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

If the structure of HTML may vary but value remains same, then you can use:

```js
$(".cat-item-15 :checkbox[value='15']").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-15">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="15">Country</label>
  <ul class="children">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-53">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="53">Canada</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-47">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="47">United Kingdom</label>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-52">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ofait-items[]" value="52">USA</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Thanks!